# Degradado con css

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Hola a todos me encuentro haciendo una pequeña vista para un formulario de acceso, el problema resulta es que no se como acomodar el siguiente degradado dentro de la pantalla, hasta el momento tengo el siguiente código para el formulario.

```
<div class="login">
 <div class="account-login">
h1>Iniciar Sesión</h1>
                            <form action="" class="login-form" method="POST">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Correo Electronico" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control text-white">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-l">Iniciar Sesión</button>
                                <a href="recuperar.php" class="float-right link mt-2">Olvidé mi contraseña</a>
                                <p class="mt-2 text-left"><a href="registro.php" class="link">Crear Una Cuenta</a></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Que me muestra en pantalla lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo el codigo del degradado que necesito pero no se como ubicarlo para que se vea de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agregar el cod del degradado

Comment: @ErickCastillo codigo-> rgb(0, 0, 139)

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr el efecto del gradient podrías aplicarle un style al body de la siguiente manera:

```
    <style>

html,body {
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(27,3,3);
background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(27,3,3,1) 0%, rgba(0,16,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 54%);
background-repeat: no-repeat
}

</style>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>

html,body {
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(27,3,3);
background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(27,3,3,1) 0%, rgba(0,16,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 54%);
background-repeat: no-repeat
}

</style>

<body class="gradient1">
  
<div class="container">
<div class="login">
 <div class="account-login">
<h1 style="color:white">Iniciar Sesión</h1>
                            <form action="" class="login-form" method="POST">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Correo Electronico" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control text-white">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-l">Iniciar Sesión</button>
                                <a href="recuperar.php" class="float-right link mt-2">Olvidé mi contraseña</a>
                                <p class="mt-2 text-left"><a href="registro.php" class="link">Crear Una Cuenta</a></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```